# How can I install my Sims 3 expansion packs?

Tags: 13.04, games

I just installed Ubuntu 13.04 and I like it.

However, I can't figure out how to install my sims3 expsansion packs from origin through winehq. Usually on Windows's I'm able to play my sims 3 after installation without origin being open. (Without running/having origin open)

Comment: You may be interested in [PlayOnLinux](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/playonlinux/). Give it a try: it's very simple, easy to use and effective.

Answer (score 2):

In short, no... but you might be able to play them using Wine... which you can learn more about [here](http://www.winehq.org/) and also find there compatibility list...

Answer (score 1):

It depends. Like @Gui said, basically no.

However, if you install WINE (Wine Is Not an Emulator), it allows you to run Windows programs and the necessary drivers, system files, and whatnot that you might need to run the program. I had a Windows game I attempted to run under WINE, and it was very laggy and the Framerate was awful.

Check out the link @Gui gave you, and try from there.

PS...How to install WINE (and you will also want Winetricks): 
Enter this at the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install wine winetricks
```

That will make sure everything is up to date before and after installing WINE/Winetricks.